# Un/Hide Rows base on cell change of two different cells Un/Hiding different parts of the sheet independently

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very simple code that works very well to Un/Hide rows when change the cell value of S55. BUT I need a code but works exactly the same for two portions of my sheet independently.

I mean changing the first cell un/hide some rows at the beggining  and on the other side changing another cell at the end of the sheet un/hide others rows differents of the one at the beggining.

here is the code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim HideRows As Range, ViewRows As Range

If Intersect([s55], Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Select Case [s55].Value
    Case Is = 0
        Set HideRows = Rows("60:298")
        Set ViewRows = Nothing

End Select
On Error Resume Next
HideRows.Hidden = True
ViewRows.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Cross-posted at: 
https://chandoo.org/forum/threads/un-hide-rows-base-on-cell-change-for-two-different-cells-un-hiding-different-parts-of-the-sheet-independently.44047/
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/un-hide-rows-base-on-cell-change-for-two-different-cells-un-hiding-different-parts-of-the-sheet-independently.1130372/
https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1312392-un-hide-rows-base-on-cell-change-for-two-different-cells-un-hiding-different-parts-of-the.html. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Comment: Also cross-posted at: https://www.excelguru.ca/forums/showthread.php?10561-Un-Hide-Rows-base-on-cell-change-for-two-different-cells-Un-Hiding-different-parts-of

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement isn't entirely clear because you don't specify which rows to be affected in which way. However, you may try to modify the code below to work in the way you want.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim HideRows As Range, ViewRows As Range

    With Target
        Select Case .Address
            Case [S55].Address
                If .Value = 0 Then
                    Set HideRows = Rows("60:298")
                    Set ViewRows = Rows("3:5")
                End If
            Case [S1].Address
                If .Value = 0 Then
                    Set HideRows = Rows("3:5")
                    Set ViewRows = Rows("60:298")
                End If
        End Select

        On Error Resume Next
        HideRows.Hidden = True
        ViewRows.Hidden = False
    End With
End Sub
```

First, follow the `Select` statement. It has 2 "Cases". Case #1 will take effect if the clicked cell (*Target*) is [S1], the second if it's [S55]. If neither of these is applicable then nothing will be done (because the user clicked elsewhere).

Of course [S55] is the cell you already know but [S1] is a new one. You can change the cell address to the one you want to use.

The procedure sets 2 ranges. One is called `HideRows`. It's a group of rows which you want to be hidden. The other is called `ViewRows` and comprises of the rows you want to make visible. Most of the time neither of these ranges is set and the code can't do anything to them. In your existing code the second capability goes unused.

Now, just because you clicked [S55] doesn't mean that anything will happen to these two ranges. The code first looks at the value you entered. It will take action only if you entered 0 (zero). Here is the code that checks this: `If .Value = 0 Then`. I set the same condition for [S1] but it's easy to change.

Now, if [S55] was changed and now has a value of 0, both ranges `HideRows` and `ViewRows` will be set. Rows("60:298") will be hidden and Rows("3:5") will be made visible. Of course, if the latter were visible before the instruction will have no effect. Also, of course, the range is easy to change.

You didn't mention which rows to hide when [S1] is set to 0. The above code says `Set HideRows = Rows("3:5")` and it's easy to change. The next line says `Set ViewRows = Rows("60:298")`. This is easy to change, too. Or you can just delete the line. If you do that, the range `ViewRows` will not be set to anything and nothing will be shown that wasn't shown before.

As the code is set up it's a toggle, hiding and showing the same rows for [S1] and [S55]. That's cute but probably not useful. The point is to show how to do it. For example, you might let the code react to entries of either 0 or 1 - only hide something when 0 is entered and only show something when the entry is 1.

It's also easy to add more cells that react to the Change event and let different things happen in response to the changes there. It can all be done with the present code structure. Therefore it's time well spent if you learn how to master it.